# How to implement different tax and currencies within a single website installation?

Tags: magento-1.9

I work with the Magento Community Version 1.9.1. Is it possible to have different tax rates and currencies? Currently I have defined one website, one store and three store views.

I would like to have:

Store View A > Currency: Swiss Francs > Tax Rate: 8 % 
Store View B > Currency: Euro > Tax Rate: 20% 
Store View C > Currency: Dollar > Tax Rate: 11%

Within a Store View the tax rate should be fixed for all customers.

Is this possible or do I need to define three Websites in order to handle separate tax rates and currencies?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three websites, one for each checkout currency and then you have to have batch routines that updates the pricing from the base price as it's not automatic.